# How to run tests in a folder in maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using spring-boot. I have my tests segregated in the following manner

```
tests
    |java 
       |endtoend
         |org.mycompany.tests
       |integration
         |org.mycompany.tests
       |unit
         |org.mycompany.tests
```

When I run a mvn test or package everything inside tests folder are running. I want to run the test within individual folders. Intellij is able to run unit, integaration and endtoend separately.

I saw posts for running tests within a package. All my different test folders have the same package structure. So filtering by test packages will not help me.

If intellij is able to run the folders individually, I think I am just missing the command to run it from the cmd line. Please advise.

Comment: The tests should be categories by using naming conventions like unit tests should be named like `*Test.java` and usually are in the same package as the class they are testing. If you have integration tests they should be named like `*IT.java` and run by maven-failsafe-plugin and shouldn't be separated by packages... And also the tests should be located to the module they belong to ...

Comment: @prabha Have you tried something of this sort `mvn -Dtest="tests/java/endtoend/**" test` This should include just the tests inside endtoend folder